# Horizontal Lines Before and After Texts inside slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, slider

Want to add horzontal line inside slides.
we want inside lines in the sliders guys i am new to design these can you guys help with the code kindly answer this.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="banner.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="banner.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="banner.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div class="center">
  <span class="slide" onclick="currentSlide(1)"> 01.</span>
  <span class="slide" onclick="currentSlide(2)">02.</span>
  <span class="slide" onclick="currentSlide(3)">03.</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I attached the image for reference kindly answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
.slide:not(:last-child)::after {
    margin: 4px 5px;
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but also you can create additional spans between.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.slide:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slide:after,
.slide:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  right: -10px;
}

.slide:before {
  left: -10px;
  right: auto;
}

.slide:first-child:after {
  right: -10px;
}

.slide:last-child:after {
  left: -10px;
}

.slide:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.center:after {
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  right: -40%;
  left: 10px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <span class="slide"> 01.</span>
  <span class="slide">02.</span>
  <span class="slide">03.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033095/how-should-add-below-section-using-this-code-in-codepen-anyone-know-about-this-i