# How should add below section using this code in codepen anyone know about this i want to add about section and work section under this header

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, google-web-designer

[code pen link](https://codepen.io/lmgonzalves/pen/djEgmv) Add section below the header i tried but its not working
Here will be injected sliders for images, numbers, titles and links, Simple pagination for the slider, Container for all sliders, and pagination

```
<div class="container">
    <main class="sliders-container">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="pagination__item"><a class="pagination__button"></a></li>
            <li class="pagination__item"><a class="pagination__button"></a></li>
            <li class="pagination__item"><a class="pagination__button"></a></li>
            <li class="pagination__item"><a class="pagination__button"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/lmgonzalves/pen/djEgmv

Comment: Use this link want to add some sections